# printf prompt appears after the user input

Tags: c

I'm starting learning C reading the Deitel manual and in the second chapter they talk about prompt that make users enter number values (integers). But the prompt asking the user to enter a number doesn't appear when I run the function, instead it appears after I entered the two numbers requested.

How do I solve this?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
printf("Enter two integers, and I will tell you\\n");
  
    printf("the relationship they satisfy:");  
    int num1; //first number   
    int num2; //second number    
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);    
  
    if (num1 == num2) {       
       printf("%d is equal to %d\\n", num1, num2);   
    }    
    if (num1 != num2) {
       printf( "%d is not equal to %d\\n", num1, num2);
    }   
}
```

The results when I run it:

```
8
4
Enter two integers, and I will tell you
the relationship they satisfy:8 is not equal to 4
```

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`.

Comment: Aside: the newline ouput as `\\n` should be `\n`.